# make every labels different in doughnut chart (react js)

Tags: reactjs

i have double doughnut chart in my react js project code. in that double chart dougnut i want to have 3 different labels in 3 different colour, what should i write to make that?

this my code now

```
        var dataDoughnut1 = {
        labels: ["Blue", "Green", "Red"],
        datasets: [{
          data: [1000],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#36A2EB"
          ],
          labels: [
            'Blue',
          ]
        }, {
          data: [400,600],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#C4D34C",
            "#F7464A"
          ],
          labels: [
            'Green',
            'Red'
          ],
        }],
      };
```

until now with that code the output labels is "blue","green" and "green" again
i want to make 3 different labels in 3 different colour too, anyone can help me?

result :

[image: this the updated result]

Comment: which library you are using ?

Comment: i use MDBContainer

Comment: in this array  labels: ['Green','Red'] have you tried to add a third color ?

Comment: yes, i already tried and the result is same "blue","green" and "blue" again in red colour

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so i have read the docs of react-chartjs-2 and their Doughnut Chart does not support rendering two datasets like you want, i came up with this workaround that will help you to achieve what you want.

```
import React from "react";
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { MDBContainer } from "mdbreact";

const App = () => {
  var dataDoughnut1 = {
    labels: ["Blue", "Green", "Red"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [1000, 0, 0],
        //You should set here all the other colors desired from the other datasets so it can be interpreted by the component
        backgroundColor: ["#36A2EB"],
        labels: ["Blue"],
      },
      {
        data: [400, 600],
        backgroundColor: ["#C4D34C", "#F7464A"],
        labels: ["Green", "Red"],
      },
    ],
  };
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
          console.log(tooltipItem.datasetIndex);
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var index = tooltipItem.index;

          return dataset.labels[index] + ": " + dataset.data[index];
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return (
    <MDBContainer>
      <h3 className="mt-5">Doughnut chart</h3>
      <Doughnut data={dataDoughnut1} options={options} />
    </MDBContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the result [image]

Comment: i already try oyur code and i have updated my result... the result is label "blue" in blue colour, label "red" in red colour and label "blue" in green colour. so i want to have 3 different label, and now only have two different label

Comment: I have updated my answer, no you have a fully worked chat with the colored labels.

Comment: did that hap^pen to resolve the issue ? if so do not forget to accept the answer for future references